# Concatenated string does not equal literal string?

Tags: ruby, string, equality

I am trying to play with regexes and test my own code in ruby. Using the example below, I would anticipate the final puts to return true, but it does not. The check_password method does, however, return "Your pw does not work because it is too short" Why doesn't the true/false check return true?

```
def err_message(reason)
  puts "Your pw does not work because " + reason
end

def check_password(password)
    if password.length<6
        return err_message("it is too short")
    elsif password.index(/[A-Z]/)==nil
        return err_message("it does not contain a capital letter")
    elsif password.index(/\d|[!,@,#,$,%,&,*,+,:,?]/)==nil
        return err_message("it needs either a digit or special character")
    elsif password.index(/([!,@,#,$,%,&,*,+,:,?\w])/)>0
        return err_message("nope. !,@,#,$,%,&,*,+,:,? are the only special characters available")
    else
        return "Valid Password!"
    end
end

puts check_password("aaaaa")=="Your pw does not work because it is too short"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`err_message` would evaluate `puts "Your pw does not work because " + reason` and return `nil` since `nil` is the return value from `puts`, change the method definition to look like below:

```
def err_message(reason)
  "Your pw does not work because " + reason
end
```

then:

```
puts check_password("aaaaa")=="Your pw does not work because it is too short"
# => true
```

Comment: The added method is to account for multiple validations that have not been added. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are referring to??

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions for improving your method.  Normally I would make it with a comment, but formatting restrictions make that impractical in this case.  Consider writing it like this:

```
SPECIAL_CHARS = '!@#$%&*+:?'

def check_password(password)
  "Your pw does not work because " +
  case
  when password.length < 6
    "it is too short"
  when password.match(/[A-Z]/).nil?
    "it does not contain a capital letter"
  when password.match(/\d|[{SPECIAL_CHARS}]/).nil?
    "it needs either a digit or special char"
  else
    return "Valid Password!"
  end
end  

check_password("abcde")
  #=> "Your pw does not work because it is too short" 
check_password("abcdef")
  #=> "Your pw does not work because it does not contain a capital letter"
check_password("abcdeF")
  #=> "Your pw does not work because it needs either a digit or special char"
check_password("abcdeF@")
  #=> "Valid Password!"
check_password("abcdeF1")
  #=> "Valid Password!"
```

I removed

```
  when password.index(/([!,@,#,$,%,&,*,+,:,?\w])/) > 0
    "nope. !,@,#,$,%,&,*,+,:,? are the only special characters available"
```

because I didn't understand what it was checking for.

Notice that there is only one `return`, and that is when the password is valid. If the password is not valid, the result of the `case` statement (a string) is added to the string, `"Your pw does not work because "` and returned (since it would be the last statement executed by the method--no `return` needed).

I replaced  `index` with `match`, though you could alternatively write:

```
when !(password =~ /[A-Z]/)
```

or

```
when !password[/[A-Z]/]
```